# What guarantees does C provide about enum ordinal values

Tags: c, enums, standards, portability, standards-compliance

When I convert enum to integer type, what can I expect?

- Does the first variant have value of 0?
- Does the variant ordinal number increment by 1?

Assume that I did not explicitly provide the values.

---

If you like code, then the questions are here:

```c
enum foo
{
    A,
    B,
};

int
main(void)
{
    assert(A == 0);
    assert(B == 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum.

Comment: This is "guaranteed" by the C specification.

Comment: jiwopene, why do you want this guarantee?  What real coding issue depends on it?

Comment: @chux, When serializing enums or displaying its value to a user, it is easy to  look up a symbol in an array of strings if we have that guarantee. Otherwise we would have to write a messy switch statement.

Comment: @HAL9000 I was hoping to hear from jiwopene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the first variant have value of 0?

Yes.

> Does the variant ordinal number increment by 1?

Yes.

> What guarantees does C provide about enum ordinal values

From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2) :

> [...] If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant. [...]